# Why is the media assuming Iran did actually try to kidnap Masih Alinejad?

Tags: united-states, iran, media

Recently four Iranians were [accused](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/bc-us-iranian-kidnapping-plot-charges_n_60ee67abe4b0a771e7fee785) of plotting to kidnap activist Masih Alinejad. Since then we've had articles like these in the media:

- [Activist targeted in kidnapping plot says Iran is testing the US and 'to take no action signals weakness'](https://xn--mgbabxqb2mn8b.com/2021/07/activist-targeted-in-kidnapping-plot-says-iran-is-testing-the-us-and-to-take-no-action-signals/)
- [Iran's attempted kidnapping of American journalist not the first nefarious plot on US soil](https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/news/iran-kidnap-american-citizen-not-first-time)
- [Iranian kidnapping plot shows that transnational abductions are becoming 'mainstream,' human rights activists say](https://uk.news.yahoo.com/iranian-kidnapping-plot-shows-that-transactional-abductions-are-becoming-mainstream-human-rights-activists-say-221229513.html)

In other words pretty much everybody (at least as reported by the media) is assuming Iran actually did plot to kidnap Masih Alinejad, even though the four Iranians were only accused, not convicted, and presumption of innocence is a fundamental legal right.

Why is this happening? The obvious explanation is bias, and that people are believing what they want to believe, but I'm hoping a more prosaic explanation exists as to why the media is choosing to assume guilt.

Comment: I don't understand your point *presumption of innocence is a fundamental legal right.* *Media coverage isn't a court* and there is no presumption of innocence involved.  Additionally, Iran has a long fraught history wrt dealing with its expat dissidents, so it has only itself to blame if guilt is assumed, *by the press*, before much investigating.

Comment: Presumption of innocence only applies in a trial, where the prosecution has to convince a jury of guilt beyond a reasonable doubt.  The rest of us, including the media, are free to form our own opinions based on what is known, including the parties' past behavior.  The current Iranian regime has a long history of kidnapping people, which makes it quite credible that its agents would plot to kidnap this person.

Comment: @jamesqf, there are legal systems where the press is barred from publishing details e.g. of minors accused of a crime, or even the name of adult defendants if the defendant had not been a public figure before the crime. And systems where courts can pass gag orders.

Comment: Looks like I found the Wikipedia page on Trial by Media too late for this question. It has a nice, relevant example in it, too. I'm disappointed but don't suppose much can be done. /shrug

Comment: @o.m. That doesn't actually affect jamesqf's point. If "the rest of us" *don't know* about a particular trial, those who do can still form a opinion about the participants

Comment: @Allure self-answering is always an option if you can make a good one

Comment: @EkadhSingh it's too late for that though. If I had seen the Wikipedia article earlier, I wouldn't have asked this question because it strongly indicates the guess in the OP is correct. If I write that as an answer, it'll likely attract downvotes too.

Comment: @o.m.: Sure, but 1) The US is not, in general, one of those systems; 2) None of the participants are minors; 3) It's my understanding that all those named in the plot are still in Iran, so the matter can't really come before a US court; 4)  Even if it was before a court, gag orders are only used in limited situations.  This isn't one where it would be appropriate.  Ask on the Law site if you want to know more.

Comment: @jamesqf, there was a co-conspirator arrested in the US. And my comment applied to your comment which tried to generalize.

Comment: I'm an Iranian that I live in the US for a couple of years now. Are you Iranian too? If no, what do you know about the Islamic Republic regime in Iran? Islamic Republic regime has a dark history of kidnapping and killing their opponents especially in European countries, particularly Germany, so, "innocence is a fundamental legal right" NO, such right should not be exercised by someone that their history of murdering and kidnapping the opponents is a known fact...

Answer (score 3):

It is completely normal that the press is informed of criminal charges *before* there is a final verdict. How the international press deals with it depends on the reputation of the legal system in question, and despite the hits it took during the previous presidency, the US is still considered a credible source of information. Compare this [BBC report on Iran](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-57830677) and this [BBC report on Belarus](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-57702516).

- Both start with the information that a foreign government made a claim.
- Both say that another foreign government denied the claim.
- It is pretty obvious which set of claims the BBC judged credible and which it judged not credible.
- But you might notice that the BBC did not repeat the names of the four fugitive main conspirators, just their supposed affilations.

Comment: It need not even be a matter of US criminal charges.  Consider for instance that the murder of Haiti's President has been widely covered, and the names of alleged participants mentioned, even though the matter is unlikely to come before a US court.  Or the Florida condominum collapse, where the possibility of criminal charges is covered in the media.  Or just about ANY newsworthy event that might involve a crime.